# Ajuda em como juntar estas duas queries MySql

Tags: mysql

> Encontrei o opção UNION ALL mas os resultados são mostrados um embaixo
>   do outro, gostaria que criasse uma coluna para cada disciplina

Possuo estas duas queries e gostaria de juntar as duas, a diferença entre elas é que uma possui uma coluna chamada `MediaMT` e na outra `MediaPT`, também há uma diferença entre as duas em uma linha do where, onde em uma está  `SUBSTR(qc.name,8) = "MATEMATICA"` e na outra está  `SUBSTR(qc.name,8) = "PORTUGUES"` gostaria que no resultado estas duas colunas fossem mostradas uma do lado da outra, seria:

MediaPT | MediaMT | MediaGeral ...

Segue as queries:

> Query para MediaPT

```
select avg(IFNULL(fraction, 0))*10 as MediaPT, gg.finalgrade as NotaGeral,        u.firstname as Aluno, u.username as Usuario, u.lastname as siem, qas.userid, u.department as Turma, u.institution as Escola, qc.name as cat

FROM mdl_question_attempt_steps qas

inner join mdl_user u on u.id=qas.userid
INNER JOIN mdl_question_attempts qa ON qa.id=qas.questionattemptid
INNER JOIN mdl_question q On q.id=qa.questionid
inner join mdl_grade_grades gg on gg.userid=u.id
INNER JOIN mdl_grade_items gi ON gi.`id` = gg.`itemid`
INNER JOIN mdl_quiz_slots qs ON qs.questionid=qa.questionid
Inner Join mdl_quiz quiz ON quiz.id=qs.quizid
inner join mdl_question_categories qc ON qc.id=q.category

where substring(u.department,2,1) = 4

 and substr(gi.itemname,1)= 4
 and substr(gi.itemname,-1)= 1

 and substr(quiz.ano,1,4)=2018
 and u.lastname=213

 and substr(quiz.name,1)= 4
 and substr(quiz.name,-1)= 1


 AND itemtype = "mod"
 AND itemmodule = "quiz"
 AND finalgrade != "NULL"

 and qas.state!="todo"
 and qas.state!="complete"
 and aggregationstatus = "used"

 and SUBSTR(qc.name,8) = "PORTUGUES" 


and qs.slot=qa.slot

group by turma, u.id

ORDER BY turma ASC, `Aluno` ASC
```

> Query para MediaMT

```
select avg(IFNULL(fraction, 0))*10 as MediaMT, gg.finalgrade as NotaGeral,        u.firstname as Aluno, u.username as Usuario, u.lastname as siem, qas.userid, u.department as Turma, u.institution as Escola, qc.name as cat

FROM mdl_question_attempt_steps qas

inner join mdl_user u on u.id=qas.userid
INNER JOIN mdl_question_attempts qa ON qa.id=qas.questionattemptid
INNER JOIN mdl_question q On q.id=qa.questionid
inner join mdl_grade_grades gg on gg.userid=u.id
INNER JOIN mdl_grade_items gi ON gi.`id` = gg.`itemid`
INNER JOIN mdl_quiz_slots qs ON qs.questionid=qa.questionid
Inner Join mdl_quiz quiz ON quiz.id=qs.quizid
inner join mdl_question_categories qc ON qc.id=q.category

where substring(u.department,2,1) = 4

 and substr(gi.itemname,1)= 4
 and substr(gi.itemname,-1)= 1

 and substr(quiz.ano,1,4)=2018
 and u.lastname=213

 and substr(quiz.name,1)= 4
 and substr(quiz.name,-1)= 1


 AND itemtype = "mod"
 AND itemmodule = "quiz"
 AND finalgrade != "NULL"

 and qas.state!="todo"
 and qas.state!="complete"
 and aggregationstatus = "used"

 and SUBSTR(qc.name,8) = "MATEMATICA" 


and qs.slot=qa.slot

group by turma, u.id

ORDER BY turma ASC, `Aluno` ASC
```

> Encontrei o opção `UNION ALL` mas os resultados são mostrados um embaixo do outro, gostaria que criasse uma coluna para cada disciplina

Comment: Em qual dessas tabelas está a coluna `fraction`?

Comment: @VictorStafusa, isso mesmo, a coluna `fraction` está em  `qas`

Comment: vou testar sua resposta, mas desde já agradeço muito o trabalho que teve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, acho que a parte do `and qs.slot=qa.slot` deveria ser movida para dentro do `JOIN` correspondente.

Vou chutar que as colunas `itemtype`, `itemmodule`, `finalgrade` e `aggregationstatus` estão nas tabelas `gg` e `gi`. Se eu tiver errado esses chutes, me avise.

Esse é o grafo de tabelas que você tem:

```
         qc --- q
                |
quiz --- qs --- qa --- qas --- u --- gg --- gi
```

Nesse grafo, o `qc` é na primeira query `PORTUGUES` e na segunda é `MATEMATICA`. Cada resultado, antes de ser aplicado o `GROUP BY`, trás exatamente uma tupla de cada uma dessas tabelas.

O que acontece é que você vai precisar trazer duas tuplas de algumas tabelas para fazer o join, uma de português e uma de matemática (antes do `GROUP BY`). Dessa forma, você terá um grafo assim:

```
          pqc --- pq
                  |
pquiz --- pqs --- pqa --- pqas
                          |
                          u --- gg --- gi
                          |
mquiz --- mqs --- mqa --- mqas
                  |
          mqc --- mq
```

Onde as tabelas começando com `p` são das perguntas em português e as começando com `m` são das perguntas de matemática. Novamente, uma tupla de cada tabela do grafo acima é escolhida antes de ser feito o `GROUP BY`. Ocorre que há casos onde a mesma tabela física aparece em dois lugares diferentes no grafo como se fossem duas tabelas diferentes.

A query fica assim:

```
-- Campos a selecionar.
SELECT
    AVG(IFNULL(pqas.fraction, 0)) * 10 AS MediaPT,
    AVG(IFNULL(mqas.fraction, 0)) * 10 AS MediaMT,
    gg.finalgrade AS NotaGeral,
    u.firstname AS Aluno,
    u.username AS Usuario,
    u.lastname AS siem,
--  u.id, -- removido
    u.department AS Turma,
    u.institution AS Escola,
    pqc.name AS catp,
    mqc.name AS catm

-- Tabelas que independem da disciplina.
FROM mdl_user u
INNER JOIN mdl_grade_grades gg ON gg.userid = u.id
INNER JOIN mdl_grade_items gi ON gi.`id` = gg.`itemid`

-- Tabelas para relacionar as tuplas de português.
INNER JOIN mdl_question_attempt_steps pqas ON u.id = pqas.userid
INNER JOIN mdl_question_attempts pqa ON pqa.id = pqas.questionattemptid
INNER JOIN mdl_question pq ON pq.id = pqa.questionid
INNER JOIN mdl_quiz_slots pqs ON pqs.questionid = pqa.questionid AND pqs.slot = pqa.slot
INNER JOIN mdl_quiz pquiz ON pquiz.id = pqs.quizid
INNER JOIN mdl_question_categories pqc ON pqc.id = pq.category

-- Tabelas para relacionar as tuplas de matemática.
INNER JOIN mdl_question_attempt_steps mqas ON u.id = mqas.userid
INNER JOIN mdl_question_attempts mqa ON mqa.id = mqas.questionattemptid
INNER JOIN mdl_question mq ON mq.id = mqa.questionid
INNER JOIN mdl_quiz_slots mqs ON mqs.questionid = mqa.questionid AND mqs.slot = mqa.slot
INNER JOIN mdl_quiz mquiz ON mquiz.id = mqs.quizid
INNER JOIN mdl_question_categories mqc ON mqc.id = mq.category

-- Parte do WHERE que não depende de disciplina.
WHERE substring(u.department, 2, 1) = 4
AND substr(gi.itemname, 1) = 4
AND substr(gi.itemname, -1) = 1
AND itemtype = "mod"
AND itemmodule = "quiz"
AND gg.finalgrade != "NULL"
AND aggregationstatus = "used"
AND u.lastname = 213

-- Parte do WHERE para filtrar apenas português nas tabelas p.
AND SUBSTR(pquiz.ano, 1, 4) = 2018
AND SUBSTR(pquiz.name, 1) = 4
AND SUBSTR(pquiz.name, -1) = 1
AND pqas.state != "todo"
AND pqas.state != "complete"
AND SUBSTR(pqc.name, 8) = "PORTUGUES"

-- Parte do WHERE para filtrar apenas matemática nas tabelas m.
AND SUBSTR(mquiz.ano, 1, 4) = 2018
AND SUBSTR(mquiz.name, 1) = 4
AND SUBSTR(mquiz.name, -1) = 1
AND mqas.state != "todo"
AND mqas.state != "complete"
AND SUBSTR(mqc.name, 8) = "MATEMATICA"

-- Final da query.
GROUP BY turma, u.id
ORDER BY turma ASC, `Aluno` ASC
```

Essa abordagem não é muito escalável para o caso de você querer resultados com 30 disciplinas diferentes. Nesse caso, sugiro você mostrar como é a modelagem das tabelas envolvidas para obter uma resposta mais aprofundada. Além disso, algumas coisas que você coloca nas cláusulas `WHERE` (em especial `SUBSTR`) sugere fortemente que o seu banco de dados precisa de algum tipo de reestruturação, se isso for possível.

Comment: MUUUIIITTTOOO obrigado Victor, só precisei remover o `u.userid` do field list, deu como desconhecida e tbm não preciso deste campo, e precisei editar na `on clause` de `qa` para `pqa` em `português` e `qa` para `mqa` de `matemática`

Comment: @MiguelSilva Esse `qa` para `pqa` e `mqa` foi um erro de digitação bobo. No caso do `u.userid`, era para ter sido `u.id`, mas já que você não precisa dessa coluna, melhor assim.

Comment: estou com um pequeno problema, caso tenha apenas notas de português não me é retornado nenhum dado, como posso fazer para mostrar dados caso tenha notas apenas de uma disciplina? ou seja pode ter vezes que notas das duas disciplinas mas às vezes tenho apenas de uma disciplina.